# Front derailleur replacement

Tags: derailleur

I'm not a pro cycler and I bought this Schwinn hybrid bike at a local shop, the front derailleur is not working properly and it seems very cheap and I'd like to change it for something more durable. It's there any recommendation on the type and quality replacement for this 50T, 3x7 speed set up bike?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you able to provide any more details on what is wrong with the front deraillieur. We'd also need to know what derailliur is on there now and/or the specific manufacturer/model/year as these parts are not universal

Comment: Only problem is that it doesn't shift correctly, and to be honest, it doesn't look good quality, doesn't have any marks or brand on it, color its black. And if I have to adjust this one to make it work, I thought it may be worthy to install a better one.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I appreciate it.

Comment: Including a photo in your post is a big help for questions like this. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

In my personal experience I've found that front derailleurs make little difference to the shifting. I have noticed very little difference between my new Ultergra, my 15 year old daily Tiagra and the 2nd hand supermarket bike to leave at the train station in the morning.

Front derailleurs should take very little time to set up as they are simple brute force devices. Poor performance comes from sticky pivots after years of neglect and generally worn cables.

If you are set on replacing I've linked to the [Sheldon Brown](https://sheldonbrown.com/front-derailers.html) article which should give you some details on how to identify what you have so you can find something similar to replace with